# <a> tag not covering correct area of <div>

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have the following:

HTML:

```
    <div id="about" class="menu1"> <a href="#">About</a></div>
    <div id="aboutsub">
        <div id="team" class="menu2"> <a href="">Team</a></div>
        <div id="experience" class="menu2"> <a href="">Experience</a></div>
        <div id="difference" class="menu2"> <a href="">Difference</a></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu1
{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 60px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}

.menu1 a
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu2
{
    position: absolute;
    background: purple;
    width: 80px;
    height: 42px;
    left: 115px;
}

.menu2 a
{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Fully viewable here:
http://jsfiddle.net/snk42/1/embedded/result/

The problem I am having, is when I check the `<a>` element inside `#about`, I see the area start at the top left of the word "about", rather than filling the whole div.

How can I more easily center the text vertically while making the whole div clickable?

Also, I'm wrestling with why the `menu2` tags aren't clickable if someone knows.

Comment: Do you need to use `<a>` tags or can you just use a clickable div?

Comment: In theory, I could take away the <a> tag and just handle the click via jquery of the div.  I am using jquery to monitor the click anyway.  That may work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the anchor the width and height of the parent div, I also recommend box-sizing this element

```
.menu1 a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    top: 0; left: 0;
}

.menu2 a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjZe4/1/ <- Fiddle

Comment: In this example, try clicking the top left of the about button.  It's not a clickable area.

Comment: Also, if you check the <a> tag, it is the area of the bounding div.  Just pushed down and right by the padding.

Comment: Thats because you have the A is an absolute positioned element, i added top: 0; left: 0; all you have to do is add padding to the element to move the words or use a vertical align/text-align to center the div... but thats up to you to finesse the CSS

Comment: I forgot I added absolute to that element while testing something.  Kept overlooking it.  Removing that makes it easy, so marking this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just increasse the height and width of the `menu2` and add some padding to the top.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/snk42/4/embedded/result

Comment: This has the same issue.  Click the top left corner of "about".  Also, menu2 has text aligned to the top now, not centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a><div></div></a>
```

Comment: This assumes everyone can use html5.  I am not assuming that.